# Missing Permissions for Microsoft Graph Add Chat message

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am trying to use Microsoft.Graph to send add a message to a chat. I have successfully found my team and created a channel for the messages to go into but when I try to actually send the message, I get a Forbidden error message. This is covered by the ticket:
[Microsoft Graph API for Teams: Send Channel/ Chat messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68732304/microsoft-graph-api-for-teams-send-channel-chat-messages) and I am getting the same problem that @Koelier originaly got.

The reason that this is not fixed is that following the answer does not fix my problem. Indeed, the ChannelMessage.ReadWrite.All does not appear in my list. I am looking for the app to run as a service, in the background so the Application Permissions is the method I need to use.

I note that I am not alone in this as @johnnycardy notes that he has had exactly the same problem as me. Furthermore, I linked to the document referenced by @nastassiar and it did not reference the ChannelMessage.ReadWrite.All at all. I can assume it did once but not anymore.

Any guidance would be gratefully received.

Answer (score 0):

Just checked the permissions to perform the same using graph explorer and the below are the ones that I had to add.

ChannelMessage.Send - Allows the app to send channel messages in Microsoft Teams, on your behalf.
Chat.ReadWrite - Allows an app to read and write your 1 on 1 or group chat messages in Microsoft Teams, on your behalf.
ChatMessage.Send - Allows an app to send one-to-one and group chat messages in Microsoft Teams, on your behalf.
Group.ReadWrite.All - Allows the app to create groups and read all group properties and memberships on your behalf. Additionally allows the app to manage your groups and to update group content for groups you are a member of.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRwN5.png)

Comment: Notice how they all say "on your behalf": those are _delegated_ permissions, which means they required a signed-in user. OP is asking for _application_ permissions.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you can't find that permission is that it doesn't exist. The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chatmessage-post) states:

> Note: Application permissions are only supported for migration. In the future, Microsoft may require you or your customers to pay additional fees based on the amount of data imported.

You can't send chat messages with application permissions, only delegated permissions, because Microsoft won't allow it. I'm guessing it's so that you're forced to instead create a bot with their Bot Framework.